# Pauzing a keylistener or actionperformed

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a game involving two players being able to shoot one another
but I'm stuck trying to get the right reaction after they've been hit. My goal is to make one of them stop moving for about a second but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

So is there an easy way to temporarily stop a keylistener or a part of an actionperformed method?

oh I almost forgot to mention I'm using java for this

Comment: Yes on the first line of your listener method, you check whether enough time has passed since the last hit, and if not you return immediately. Use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to check the time.

Comment: Or you make yourself a boolean variable that indicates whether it has to be stopped temporarily or not. And in the Keylistener or Actionperformed method you check beforehand (if(canCheck) { // then do blablabla - moving players e.g. })